# How should I calculate Ramp up time, Ramp up steps count and Hold target rate time [Second and minutes) for 1000 threads by Concurrency thread group?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

Concurrent threads - 1000
Ramp up time(secs) - 200 (1000 / 200) = 5 secs [as because I want 5 users per second]
Ramp up steps count - 0
Hold target rate time(secs) - 300 secs

Is this correct configuration?

[image]

I am expecting all correct answers. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The configuration on the screenshot matches the one you described in text.

We don't know whether it is "correct" or not.

The whole idea of ramp-up is increasing the load **gradually**, in this case you will be able to correlate the number of active virtual users with other [test metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) like response time, throughput, number of errors, etc.

The relevant part of [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group) states:

> The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen. If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10 threads up and running. Each thread will start 10 (100/10) seconds after the previous thread was begun. If there are 30 threads and a ramp-up period of 120 seconds, then each successive thread will be delayed by 4 seconds.
>
> **Ramp-up needs to be long enough to avoid too large a work-load at the start of a test, and short enough that the last threads start running before the first ones finish** (unless one wants that to happen).
>
> Start with Ramp-up = number of threads and adjust up or down as needed.

There is also [JMeter Ramp-Up Period: The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period) which provides more comprehensive explanation if needed.